# How To Stream Live Video From iPhone To a Media Server

Tags: ios, video-streaming, real-time, http-live-streaming, encoder

I can get individual uncompressed frames from the iPhone's camera in iOS4. What i need is a way to package them up with sound for streaming TO a server. I've been searching for a solution on the internet but I did not found much helping info. There are much more info about playing video streaming on iPhone from a server.

I've been trying to use ffmpeg+libx264 to encode them in a MPEG-TS container with H.264 for video and AAC for audio and sending Wowza media server in real-time, with no much luck. Anyone has any idea to get this to work? Or any other suggestion?

Comment: did u get solution, what is the client library you have u used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use `qt-faststart` to put the required streaming data at the beginning of the file. Also i am not sure why you would use MPEG-TS container for H.264/AAC, try using the standard MP4.